# Problems with terminal opening URL

Tags: python

I am using soundcloud API with python and I'm trying to open url of the song with my browser. I use this code

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=clientIdEntry.get())
track_url = urlEntry.get()
if track_url[0]!="h":
    track_url = "https://"+urlEntry.get()
else:
    track_url = urlEntry.get()
track = client.get('/resolve', url=track_url)
track_id = str(track.id)
track = client.get("/tracks/"+track_id)
stream_url = client.get(track.stream_url, allow_redirects=False)
print(track.title)
print("\n \n \n")
print(stream_url.location)
time.sleep(3)
os.system("chromium-browser "+stream_url.location)
```

But URL contains & character and terminal won't open the text that is behind that sign. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote - via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
os.system("chromium-browser '"+stream_url.location+"'")
```